# SSRS How to calculate a ratio from two subtotal in a table

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS reporting tool and I need to calculate a ratio (out/in) for two subtotal in a table.  Is there a way to do this?  All data are coming from the same DataSet.  In the example I need to divide 8649 by 2638 (absolute value).  For a ratio of 3.28

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KqYQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer without seeing your dataset but you can probably do something like this.

```
=
SUM(IIF(Fields!Processus.Value = "Production", ABS(Fields!Qte.Value), Nothing), "DataSet1")
/
SUM(IIF(Fields!Processus.Value = "Intrant", ABS(Fields!Qte.Value), Nothing), "DataSet1")
```

What this does is to 2 sums, the first sums anything where the Processus field is "Production" and then divides this by a second sum.

The second sum is similar to the first except it sums anything where the Processus field is Intrant. The difference is that we use `ABS()` to give us a positive number.

**Note:** These SUM() functions are working across the entire dataset, as defined by the `"DataSet1"` scope argument. Change this to match your dataset name exactly (case sensitive) if required.

I created a cut down version of your sample data to test and these are the results.

[image]